# $\sin^n a + \cos^n a = 1$ is only true when $n=2$

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

Prove that

$$\forall a\in\mathbb R:\quad\sin^n a + \cos^n a = 1$$
is only true when $n=2$

Comment: Welcome to the site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: for $a=\pi/2$ it is true for all $n.$

Comment: Come on, it is obvious he meant that it must hold for every $a$ :)

Comment: It should probably be specified that if it holds for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then $n=2$.

Comment: These pictures might help someone write down an actual proof... is $n\in \mathbb{N}$? http://jpmccarthymaths.com/2012/10/17/proof-by-pictures-latex-sin2nxcos2nx-has-period-latex-pi2/

Comment: Hint: If you take a number $p$, $-1<p<1$, which one is biggest $|p|^2$ or $|p|^3$? (This will not solve your exact question, but it will probably make you understand why)

Comment: Thanx Mattos. I hv not done much yet just visited mathematics and physics site.

Comment: ...more inspiration here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215150/frequency-of-a-trigonometric-function-where-is-my-mistake

Comment: @Ant: Yes, but still, OP can learn from this. It's important to say what you mean in mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because, if $a\not\equiv0 \mod\dfrac\pi 2 $, we have $\,\,0< \lvert\sin a\rvert<1$ and  $\,\,0< \lvert\cos a\rvert<1$, so that: 
$$\sin^n a\le \lvert\sin a\rvert^n<\sin^2 a\quad\text{and}\quad\cos^n a\le \lvert\cos a\rvert^n<\cos^2 a $$
for all $n>2$.

Comment: If ur logic is correct in this instance,then why is sina+cosa not equal to 1.

Comment: Because $\sin^2 a<\lvert\sin a \rvert$, and the analog for $\cos$, so that $\lvert\sin a \rvert +\lvert\cos a \rvert>1$.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:*

Set $a=\pi/4$ and then see where you end up with...

Comment: @orangeskid: thanks for the edit! that was a silly mistype.

Comment: no worries; couldn't let it gather those "hater votes"

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite equation in the form:

$$\cos^n(a) + sin^n(a) = cos^2(a) + sin^2(a)$$
$$\cos^2(a)(cos^{n-2}(a) - 1) + sin^2(a)(sin^{n-2}(a) - 1) = 0 $$

Left part is negative for $$n \not= 2$$

Comment: nice way to do it :)